# Mysql alphabetic query

Tags: mysql, sql

I need your help with the following question, not sure if it's possible:

I have a sql table like this:

```
|**id**  |**word**|
|---     |     ---|
|1       |   axxxx|
|2       |   a.....|
|.       |   a...|
|.       |   a....|
|.       |   a..|
|1000    |   a....|
|1001    |   b.....|
|1002    |   bxxxxx|
|.       |   b...|
|.       |   b..|
|.       |   .|
|60000   |   z.....|
|..      |   z..|
```

Basically, the field named 'word' contains words from A to Z and these has been already ordered alphabetical.
So i need build a query which returns the first 3 rows by each letter, and example would be:

```
|**word**|
|---|
|ab|
|abc|
|abcd|
|bc|
|bcd|
|bcde|
|cd|
|cde|
|cdef|
```

I've tried several ways but didn't succeed, and at this point I'm not sure if that is really possible do it with a single query.

Thanks in advance, I'll really appreciate your advice and help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using LIMIT within GROUP BY to get N results per group?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129693/using-limit-within-group-by-to-get-n-results-per-group)

Comment: Please share an attempt or some research.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example on the system table **mysql.help_keyword**.
In your case since your list contains only words (and not signs) you can skip the **WHERE** clause.
Please notice that I'm counting on your words to be unique.

```
select      t1.name

from                mysql.help_keyword      as t1

            join    mysql.help_keyword      as t2

            on      left(t2.name,1) =  
                    left(t1.name,1)

                and t2.name         <= 
                    t1.name

where           left(t1.name,1) between 'A' and 'Z'
            and left(t2.name,1) between 'A' and 'Z'

group by        left(t1.name,1)
               ,t1.name

having          count(*) <= 3

order by        t1.name
;
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your helping

I've already solved the question, with the follow query:

```
select word from words w,  ( select min(id) as ids from words group by left(word,1) ) as ids  where w.id between ids.ids and (ids.ids + 2);
```

It's a bit dirty, but works for me and the query is faster.